# Can a SOAP application and a REST application both be hosted via IIS on the same server?

Tags: rest, soap, iis-7

I apologize in advance, if this question doesn't make sense. I'm a newbie.

I have a server that hosts, via IIS 7.0, several SOAP services. I now need to write a different service using the REST model. Can this be hosted on the same server as my other services?

The senior developers that I work with don't think it's possible, but no one seems to be sure one way or the other.

Thanks for any help or pointers you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can even be hosted within the same WebSite within IIS.
IIS doesn't care what your website is implementing, it just passes the requests along.

I'm hosting SOAP for Silverlight pages, and REST for client applications within the same Website.

All you really need to do is properly setup your endpoint configurations in Web.Config

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear. These are seperate applications with seperate Web.Config files. I don't need them hosted on the same WebSite, just the same server.

Comment: @Macromika Sure, that is also possible. Again, just make sure your endpoint configurations are setup correctly for SOAP or REST in their respective config files. No additional IIS settings changes should be needed with regards to the services